# Gnome Shell mouse shortcut to switch workspace

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, mouse, workspaces, gconf

How can I switch workspaces in gnome shell with extra mouse buttons? I`ve used to do it with compiz in unity and gnome2, but I can`t bind it in gnome shell. I want use both Up/Down and extra mouse button on my old Logitech MX Revolution.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You can set the keyboard shortcut for this though by opening **Keyboard** in **System Settings**. Switch to the Shortcuts tab and click Navigation on the left. Scroll to the bottom and you can set the keyboard shortcuts for *"Move to workspace above"* and *"Move to workspace below"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install easystroke, it allows you to define a mouse gesture to emulate keybinding, execute shell commands, hold down modifiers and emulate a scroll wheel http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```